# How to clone, or migrate, an old Ubuntu file system to a new (SAS) drive?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, backup

I have one HP server and two drives in RAID 1. On those drives we have the Ubuntu operating system.

This morning one drive failed. So now I want my system file and data. So I bought two new hard disks that I can clone old my Ubuntu (18.04) system onto.

I tried with this command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb2 of=/media/usb/backup.img
```

On `sdb2` we have the Linux system) and we restored in other system via this command:

```
sudo dd if=/media/usb/backup.img of=/dev/sdb2
```

However it failed.

Can someone give me idea about this? How I can replace the old drive and put new one and can I use as it is?

Comment: Either mkusb, Etcher, Gnome-Disks or Startup Disk Creator should be able to restore/install your .img file to USB, if you don't mind using a GUI.

Comment: https://clonezilla.org/ can help you with that

Comment: thank you. i taken an .img file in usb and how can i restore it? @katu

Comment: @nikunjrathod you can use clonezilla again for that https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image

Comment: thanks buddy you made my day!!!